# Enumerate in python to For loop

Tags: python, enumerate

I want to convert enumerate to for loop.

```
subsets = [0]*15
subsets[0] = 2
subsets = [index + subsets[subsets[index]] for (index,value) in enumerate(subsets)]
print(subsets)
```

and the similar

```
subsets = [0]*15
subsets[0] = 2
for index,value in enumerate(subsets):
  subsets[index] = index + subsets[subsets[index]]
print(subsets)
```

But I am getting different results. Please help me about this.

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: Apparently a tricky question :)

Answer (score 3):

In the first version you will compute everything based on the initial values of subsets, in the second version you will update the elements in place.

In particular, on the first iteration you will do `subsets[0] = 0 + subsets[subsets[0]] = 0 + subsets[2] = 0`. While for the first code `subsets[0]` will be `2` until the end of the execution.

An equivalent code would be

```py
subsets = [0]*15
subsets[0] = 2
tmp = [0] * 15
for index,value in enumerate(subsets):
  tmp[index] = index + subsets[subsets[index]]
subsets = tmp
print(subsets)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first case the elements of the `subsets` list not change because you make a new list of `subsets`(Both names are same) and add the values in this list.

But In your second case you update your list values while iterating through it, THis is why you got different output.]

### Execution of your second code.

```py
subsets = [0]*15
subsets[0] = 2
for index,value in enumerate(subsets):
  subsets[index] = index + subsets[subsets[index]
print(subsets) ## [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

1. In the first iteration `(index=0)`, `index + subsets[subsets[index]]`
   (`subsets[index]=2`) and after `subsets[index]=2` (`subsets[2]=0`) result is now equal to 0 + 0 which is 0.
2. In the second iteration `(index=1)`, `index + subsets[subsets[index]]`
   (`subsets[index]=0`) and after `subsets[0]=0` (because you change the zero'th value to 0 in first iteration) (`subsets[2]=0`) result is now equal to 1 + 0 which is 1.

#### similarly your sum of `index + subsets[subsets[index]]` is always equal to index value of the iteration.

**I hope you understand**

Answer (score 0):

When you write `subsets[index] =` in the second example, the values of the original `subsets` get overwritten and is used in the next iteration, etc.

This is how to write the loop, if you don't want `enumerate`, use `for index in range(len(subsets))` and `subsets[subsets[index]]` instead of `subsets[value]`.

```
output = [] 
subsets = [2] + [0]*14
for index, value in enumerate(subsets): 
    output.append(index + subsets[value])
print(output)
```